# Discrepancy in $DISPLAY configuration required to get X to work over SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, putty, xming

I connect to two different SSH servers A and B using PuTTY+Xming from Windows.

On server A, `echo $DISPLAY` yields **localhost:10.0** (already set somehow); while on server B, I've manually set the `DISPLAY` variable to be **localhost:10.0** as well.

However, I am able to use `xclock` on server A, but not on server B. The only way I could get it to work on server B is by adding server B's IP address to Xming's `X0.hosts` configuration AND setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable to my Windows machine's IP address.

My question is, how come server A's `xclock` works with minimal setup (just enable X11 forwarding and set display location to localhost:0.0 in PuTTY), but not server B's?

In addition, how can one look for the script that set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to **localhost:10.0** on server A?

---

**Additional info:**
1) Server A has an ~/.Xauthority file that gets automatically created upon login, while server B does not.
2) Server B's /var/log/auth.log contained the following error: sshd[1404]: error: Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket.
3) I changed the hostname of Server B once before.

Comment: Related: [X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38961495/55075)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much googling, it turns out the culprit is disabled ipv6 on server B.

As a workaround, the following line needs to be added to **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

Should now work after `sudo service ssh reload`.

I found the solution [here](http://ibohm.blogspot.com/2011/12/failed-to-allocate-internet-domain-x11.html) and [here](http://www.snowfrog.net/2011/11/06/ssh-display-is-not-set-failed-to-allocate-internet-domain-x11-display-socket/).

Comment: this worked for me too. its quite surprising that its necessary given that i am logging in to a machine with an ipv4 address from a machine with an ipv4 address on my lan.

Comment: Works for me too when ssh to Debian 11 (OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022) on Fedora 36 (OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022). I disabled ipv6 too on server side.