# X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

When I do "`ssh -X abcserver`", I got message "`X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0`".
I checked online and it was suggested to solve it by switching "`X11UseLocalhost no`" to "`X11UseLocalhost yes`".

However, both my manager and I don't have this administrative privilege. I am wondering, except this solution, whether there is another option to solve the issue ? I also don't have `sudo` privilege to directly install `X11` on the server.

My local platform is:

```
Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org)
(gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02)
```

The remote platform is:

```
Linux version 3.13.0-88-generic (buildd@lgw01-16) 
(gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) 
#135-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 21:10:42 UTC 2016
```

Comment: Try `ssh -Y ...`. BTW, your question belongs to a different site of the network.

Comment: Just because you've requested X11 forwarding (normal or trusted) doesn't mean the `sshd` on the other end must allow it. That's one of the first things I'd check. Also `ssh -vv -X` (or `-Y`).

Comment: @user3159253: Which site do you think it belongs on? SO has the appropriate tags, and the general question and general answer need not be specific to the OP's platform.

Comment: looks like a topic for superuser.com or maybe for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you only see this with `git` commands then see solution in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240013/x11-forwarding-request-failed-when-connecting-to-github-com

Comment: If you don't have root privileges, fixing a problem with packages and the ssh daemon might be tricky...

Answer (score 62):

Adding the `-v` option to ssh when trying to log in will give a lot of debug information which might give a clue to exactly what the problem is, like for instance

```
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.
```

which in my case installing xauth on the server fixed the issue.

Comment: On CentOS 7, the necessary package is called `xorg-x11-xauth`.

Comment: On rhel 9, `dnf install xauth`

Answer (score 52):

I had to edit the sshd config file on the remote server to fix the issue. It worked on Ubuntu 16.04 Server:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Set `X11UseLocalhost no`
```

Save the file.

```
$ sudo service sshd restart

$ exit
```

Now it works!

```
$ ssh -X user@remotehost  
$ xclock
```

Comment: I'm told that using "X11UseLocalhost no" is  a security issue. So why is it needed? It is not needed on my Arch Linux box.

Comment: For restarting the ssh service, `sudo service ssh restart`, also works.

Comment: or `pkill -HUP sshd`, which works on more OSes

Comment: note that `pkill -HUP sshd` will kill your current session, unlike service restart

Comment: "X11UseLocalhost no" would allow X11 through proxy. I guess in usual cases the X11 forwarding server would be binding to `127.0.0.1` and listening on port `601X` where `1X` is your display number. There are some wield cases where the X11 server is not binding to `127.0.0.1` but rather other loopback address like `127.0.1.1`, so only binding to 127.0.0.1 would not work. If `X11UseLocalhost no` works for you, you can first open a x11 app (e.g. with `nohup xclock &`) then check binding address with `netstat -an |grep 601X`.

Answer (score 33):

1. `sudo apt install xauth`
2. change the line `#AddressFamily any` to `AddressFamily inet` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
3. `sudo service ssh restart`

This is enough on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

After login with `ssh -X` (or after activating the PuTTY / KiTTY option "Enable X11 forwarding") you should see that the environment variable `DISPLAY` is automatically defined to `localhost:10.0` or similar. After first successful login (with a functional X11 forwarding) the file .Xauthority will be generated. Another positive sign of success.

If you are interested to see and to understand the details of X11 forwarding within your session you can try with `lsof -i -P|grep ssh`.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my error in my ssh server logs `sshd[25305]: error: Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket.`

Comment: That should be `sudo service sshd restart` or `systemctl restart sshd`, depending on your system.

Comment: `AddressFamily inet` fixed it for me.  This is needed when IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. @Alan, this all sound incredibly complex for Ubuntu and year 2023. With "all" I mean having to resort to this weird variable to just forward X11. Can you maybe please explain why this is needed when IPv6 is disabled and whether this a change from an older state in which (I think) it worked?

Comment: @Kiteloopdesign... to be honest I have no idea why it works, but it does.

Answer (score 16):

1.make sure that during `ssh -X root@server` you have root permission.

2.update the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure this line is uncommented

```
    X11Forwarding yes
```

3.`systemctl restart sshd`

4.exit from server

5.`ssh -X root@server`

6.`virt-manager`

Answer (score 4):

After X11 forwarding suddenly stopped working after no other changes than connecting the ssh server to another wifi, I followed the answer to this seemingly [completely different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19239274/discrepancy-in-display-configuration-required-to-get-x-to-work-over-ssh) and it worked.

In other words, it seems the solution for me was to specify `AddressFamily inet` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as superuser, editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote host and changing the following line fixed it.

From

```
#X11Forwarding no
```

to

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

Then: `pkill -HUP sshd` on the remote host to make sshd reload its config, which also closes the sshd session.

Comment: Thank you this worked on my Mac too. `sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd`